# Syntax error in select query on random occasions

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a query to search the database that I am using to find if the record with 'IDnumber' in its 'SportID' column also has 'true' in its 'Substitute' column. However, when it comes to executing this query, SOMETIMES it throws the error back saying that there is a syntax error, however on other occasions (with exactly the same user inputs) it will not throw back the error.

The error is:

> {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Substitute =
>   true and SportID ='."}

Here is the code:

```
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Connection string is here);

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();


        // this part of the query determines whether there is a substitute in the sport or not
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "Select * FROM [Sport] WHERE Substitute = true and SportID = " +  Form1.IDNumber;
        if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            substituteInSport = true;

        }
        else
        {
            substituteInSport = false;
        }

        connection.Close();
```

I am unsure what to do as I cannot figure out what is making it say that there is an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error that is thrown?

Comment: {"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Substitute = true and SportID ='."}

Comment: And you should really use parameterized queries

Comment: Can you try it as `Substitute = 1` instead?

Comment: The ANSI SQL way is `Substitute IS TRUE`, perhaps that's what MS Access wants too?

Comment: seems like its not reading the form1.IDNumber field.

Comment: Yes I will be changing this to a parameter

Comment: Is that Form1 the instance of a class named Form1 or is it just the class name?

Comment: Tried 'substitute = 1' and 'substitute IS true' and both still throw the error

Comment: Form1 is the class name

Comment: `Form1` doesnt look like the typical instance name

Comment: Then your code is broken. You should use the instance of that class that contains a valid value for the property   _Form1 myForm = new Form1();_ and use myForm.IDNumber after setting it of course

Comment: Form1 is what visual studio named the first windows Form in my code, using Form1.globalVariablehere works in other parts of my code

Comment: Primary key of the table called 'Sport'

Comment: `IDNumber` is any textbox or control?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parameterized query - with the correct datatypes!
Assuming the Column `SportID`is f type `Integer` it would look like this:

```
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("the_connection_string"))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        // this part of the query determines whether there is a substitute in the sport or not
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "Select * FROM [Sport] WHERE Substitute = true and SportID = ?";
        command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.IDNumber);

        if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
            substituteInSport = true;
        else
            substituteInSport = false;
    }
```

Comment: what's more: check the value of `Form1.IDNumber`..maybe there's something wrong with that!

Comment: Answer is correct. Seems IDNumber is some `TextBox` or any other server control where needs to get value before use.

Answer (score 0):

As @CeInSql suggested you should use parameterised query to prevent SQL Injections. Also you need to fetch value of `SportID` from `Form1` for example if `IDNumber` is **textbox** from which you are fetching value, use `Form1.IDNumber.Text` to get value from user control.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("the_connection_string"))
        using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            // this part of the query determines whether there is a substitute in the sport or not
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "Select * FROM [Sport] WHERE Substitute = true and SportID = ?";
            command.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Form1.IDNumber.Text);

            if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
                substituteInSport = true;
            else
                substituteInSport = false;
        }
```

Comment: you are right if it's a textbox or some kind of control, but i may be a property aswell